# Call function every time jqueryUI function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently I have to call a function manually every time jqueryUi's slideDown/-Toggle is called.

I do it like this everytime at the moment:

```
$('.slideMeDown').slideDown();
$('.slideMeDown').promise().done(function(){
        functionICallEverytime();
    });
```

Is there any easier way to solve this? I didn´t find the passage in jqueryUI´s code to call the function from there...

Using 
jQueryUI v1.11.0
jQuery v1.7.2

Comment: try `$('.slideMeDown').slideDown(functionICallEverytime);`

Comment: the function is called instatly. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try override the slideDown function. Something like this:

```
$.slideDown = (function (originalSlideDown) {
    return function () {
        originalSlideDown.apply(this, arguments);
        functionICallEverytime();
    };
}($.slideDown));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Signature: `.slideDown( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

```
$('.slideMeDown').slideDown(400, functionICallEverytime);
```

Signature: `.slideDown( options )`

```
$('.slideMeDown').slideDown({ complete: functionICallEverytime });
```

Instead of monkey patching, create your own plugin.

```
$.fn.mySlideDown = function () {
    this.slideDown.apply(this, arguments);
    functionICallEverytime();
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can decorate original slideDown method:

```
$.fn.slideDown = (function(orig, defaultCallback) {
    return function() {
        var deferred = orig.apply(this, arguments);
        deferred.promise().done(defaultCallback);
        return deferred;
    };
})($.fn.slideDown, functionICallEverytime);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tz4Lsrry/1/

Now every time you use `$('.slideMeDown').slideDown();` `functionICallEverytime` will be called after a animation is complete.

Also `return deferred;` ensures that other non-default promises will also work:

```
$('.slideMeDown').slideDown().promise().done(function() {
    alert('another one');
});
```

Above example will execute `functionICallEverytime` and after that fire `alert('another one');`.